# Circuit Python: I have generated an array of random times between 0700 and 2300. How do I repeat this action for every day in a set number of days?

Tags: python, adafruit-circuitpython

I have the following code which generates one random time in each 30-minute slot from 0700 to 2300. Now I need to repeat this operation for every day within a set number of days, in order to get new random times for every day. How can I do this?

```
import datetime
from random import randint # random time


begin = datetime.datetime.strptime('07:00', '%H:%M')
end = datetime.datetime.strptime('23:00', '%H:%M')
delta = datetime.timedelta(minutes=30)


r = []

while begin <= end:
    r.append(begin + datetime.timedelta(seconds=randint(0, 1800)))
    begin = begin + delta
print(r)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Libraries needed:

```
import datetime
from random import randint # random time
```

Then let's define start, end and step time

```
begin = datetime.datetime.strptime('07:00', '%H:%M')
end = datetime.datetime.strptime('23:00', '%H:%M')
delta = datetime.timedelta(minutes=30)
```

The following array will store random times:

```
r = []

while begin <= end:
    r.append(begin + datetime.timedelta(seconds=randint(0, 1800)))
    begin = begin + delta
print(r)
```

Output:
[datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 7, 14, 19), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 7, 34, 46), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 8, 19, 8), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 8, 50, 23), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 9, 0, 7), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 9, 30, 27), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 10, 8, 6), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 10, 44, 53), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 11, 10, 27), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 11, 33, 37), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 12, 15, 50), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 12, 36, 41), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 13, 1, 5), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 13, 34, 56), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 14, 8, 41), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 14, 49, 12), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 15, 23, 40), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 15, 57, 32), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 16, 21, 2), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 16, 45, 40), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 17, 9), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 17, 45, 52), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 18, 0, 36), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 18, 57, 5), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 19, 13, 22), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 19, 32, 40), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 20, 1, 12), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 20, 34, 55), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 21, 2, 27), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 21, 41, 6), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 22, 24, 14), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 22, 39, 15), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 23, 14, 38)]

Comment: Thank you so much, this looks great! I am going to try it as soon as I manage to install coding sw on my pc. I am not sure if I have made some mistakes with the voting process, this was my first post and I didn’t know what the up and down arrows were for... :-(

Comment: Ok the comment. It worked here!

Comment: So yesterday I loaded the code on my adafruit Gemma M0 board and found out (from the adafruit forum) that the "datetime" module is not supported by Circuitpython... So that code is not working... Any idea about workarounds?